# Mining reputation through edits

Tags: feature-request, reputation, edits

I am not sure this is a question. It is just an observation.

Recently I noticed some people introducing obvious generalizations into questions and answers on stackoverflow. It is not that the text after the edit becomes significantly better, it is just an edit for an edit. Superficially, the change is rather innocent and is immediately accepted by someone. But when it happens to a question or an answer which is well voted in its original form, it sometimes breaks what exactly the author was saying.

Until recently this was not a problem, because there was no stimulus for doing this except for correcting typos. Today I learned, that an editor is rewarded +2 for an approved edit, and this explains why I started to notice those people.

I am not sure that editors should be rewarded for editing already voted answers (with, for example, 3 or more votes) and they should know about it.

P.S. I do not want to point to specific users.

Comment: It's called Reputation and not Karma. And rep for edits is not new. And you need at least 3 approvers. If they all fail to reject minor edits, then this is another problem.

Comment: I would say a question can be improved at any time.  The problem is people approving edits that shouldn't be approved

Comment: Not all edits are awarded 2 points. +2 reps are given to only those users who suggest an edit and then their edit is approved by multiple reviewers. If you have a certain reputation points, you can directly edit a post and you don't get the +2 reps.

Comment: @RichardTingle, yes, I agree.

Comment: Is "recently" since December 16? If so, it is the chase for Hats.